# Module collection class

Tags: python

I want to collect the modules I use all the time under a single class. Thus, I will not have to recall voices.

How can I do that?

For example, I use `pandas` library in many files. I want to keep all of my modules in a single file rather than calling this up constantly. How can I do that?

Comment: You could import all your needed classes into one python file and then import that one file instead. I don't think this is common practice, though.

Comment: You could do as @Sean suggests, but it's uncommon, because "Explicit is better than implicit" ([PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2)), and it would introduce unneeded overhead in many scripts that don't need everything.

Comment: on Linux I rather use snippets which I can simply paste in code using shortcuts in [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). But if you use IDEs then they also should have snippets. Eventually you can use [cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) to generate some code at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the first comment to your question, this is not common practice.

Nevertheless, you can import all required modules in one file. You would then only need to import this one file.

This is how it would loook.

file_with_imports.py:

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

file_calling_imports.py

```
import file_with_imports
```

One reason that this is not common practice is that the imports take up resource (memory & time) and you might be importing many more modules than are required if they are just batched into one and always called.

The other reason is that it would be cumbersome calling the modules. For example, calling the `os.path()` function would become `file_with_imports.os.path()` so the code would actually become longer.